# Sci-fi book series about time travel, taming dinosaurs, and alien psychics

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, time-travel, dinosaurs

This is a series of books that starts off with a bunch of humans being abducted and sent back in time roughly 65 million years. They start to build a civilization and take dinosaurs to help out. They are also able to climb very tall cliffs and glide on air currents to travel and scout.

Unbeknownst to them, they were sent back in time by aliens trying to prevent a galaxy wide takeover from other aliens, as it was found out too late that humans have some sort of innate resistance/ability that can stop these would be conquerors.

The other issue is that the timing of everything will make it so that after the humans wipe out the alien invaders, they will in turn be wiped out by the asteroid that kills off the dinosaurs.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Roughly when did you read this, and do you have any idea when it was published?

Comment: @LogicDictates After 1979, one would presume.

Comment: People going back to the end of the dinosaurs and stopping an alien invasion is the plot of Sawyer's [*End of an Era*](http://www.sfreviews.net/endofanera.html).  (Warning: harsh review, mild spoilers :)

Comment: Some elements are common to Philip E. High's *Blindfold from the Stars*, even if it's clearly not that.

Comment: @DavidW the review is hasty and incomplete even more than it is harsh (we are not, for example, denied Klicks' real name - it's *Miles*. Miles Jordan). And the awful conveniences *are* explained in the (not too satisfactory, I'll admit) end, even if by implicating a Deus ex Machina.

Comment: @LSerni I'm probably not as hard on the book as the review is, but it's really not that great a book, and the review is a better description of the story than, say, the google books blurb, so I figured it - with a warning - was still worth linking to.  The ending though...

Comment: Was this an e-book?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very much like the "Time Takers" series by Andrew Saxon - humans are collected from different times in history (the protagonist is from our time, but there are also ancient Romans, Atlanteans, and people from a post-apocalyptic future, etc.)

By the second book "Taming a Planet" (which is a generation later) they have tamed dinosaurs they ride.

The third book "Extinction" deals with the asteroid issue.

But I am not sure this was ever published as a physical book...

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like *Pliocene Exiles* by Julian May, but not quite.  Troublemakers get sent back in time, but get stuck between two alien factions that inspire legends of Faeries and Goblins.

Comment: If you think this is the book the OP is looking for then this is perfectly fine as an answer, in fact that’s exactly where it should go! You also cannot comment until you have 50 rep anyway. It might be worthwhile if you [edit] this to explain a bit more how this matches though. Welcome to the site! You may also want to take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Unfortunately you can't leave a comment until you earn some reputation.  It _is_ acceptable to post answers that partially match the question, as long as you carefully highlight the points that are similar, but the *Pliocene Saga* fails because it's set far later than the Mesozoic and has no dinosaurs.